# Признак конца файла

Tags: c, файлы

Что служит признаком конца файла, например, текстового?
Есть ли какой-нибудь символ конца файла, или же зная, заранее его размер, считаем количество непрочитанных байтов?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Когда-то в глубокой древности во времена DOS таким признаком для текстовых файлов теоретически служил символ Ctrl-Z (0x1A). Реально - уже тогда это не работало, а если работало - то мешало.

Если при очередном чтении оно не удалось - можно проверить состояние потока и узнать, не достигнут ли конец файла (`feof()` в C, `.eof()` в C++).

Особо подчеркиваю: проверить достижение конца файла можно **после** неудачного чтения, а не **до**. Так что проверять конец файла **до** чтения - нарываться на ошибку...

Comment: благодарю за ответ